# Build custom model from LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a model structure like this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ADDRESS")]
public class ADDRESS
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TO")]
    public string TO { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "SMS")]
public class SMSBODY
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ADDRESS")]
    public List<ADDRESS> ADDRESS { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "TEXT")]
    public string TEXT { get; set; }
}
```

I want to construct a `List<SMSBODY>` from a linq query and I am doing a foreach now as below:

```
List<studentsmsscheduler> smslist = (from n in dbContext.studentsmsschedulers
                                     select n).ToList();

List<SMSBODY> sms_body = new List<SMSBODY>();

foreach (studentsmsscheduler s in smslist)
{
    List<ADDRESS> api_smsto = new List<ADDRESS>();
    string _mob = s.MobileNo;
    api_smsto.Add(new ADDRESS {TO = _mob});

    string _message = s.Content;

    SMSBODY api_smsbody = new SMSBODY { TEXT = _message, ADDRESS = api_smsto };
    sms_body.Add(api_smsbody);
}
```

Is there any way to get this list from LINQ query itself in a faster way? (since there might be 2000+ records each time)

Comment: You can try the following approach:
`var result = (from n in dbContext.studentsmsschedulers select new SMSBODY { ADDRESS = new ADDRESS { TO = n.MobileNo }, TEXT = n.Content }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Try Following

```
var sms_body = 
   dbContext
    .studentsmsschedulers
    .Select(it => new SMSBODY {
             TEXT  = it.Content, 
             ADDRESS = new List<ADDRESS>(){ 
                 new ADDRESS { TO = it.MobileNo } } 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Above approach won't give you significant improvement, it's just simplified version of your query + less loaded data into the memory. For performance, consider using plain SQL query to retrieve the data.

Comment: but can i convert the plain sql to object directly? I have to use DataReader and then iterate through each records to make the object List<SMSBODY> right? Or is any simple approach to improve perfomance?

Comment: Also in above code To property is not set for ADDRESS Object. Can you please edit to show how to make it set

Comment: Or you can use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) it takes care of materializing object without loosing performance benefits.